# How to change the color of outliers of certain category in boxplot()?

Tags: r, boxplot, rnw

Put simply, I want to color outliers, but only if they belong to specific category, i.e. I want

```
boxplot(mydata[,2:3], col=c("chartreuse","gold"), outcol="red")
```

but `red`  only for those elements for which `mydata[,1]`  is `M` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `outcol` only specifies one color per variable (box). However, you can use `points` to overplot individual points any way that you want. You need to figure out the relevant x and y coordinates to use for plotting. When you make a boxplot with a statement like `boxplot(mydata[,2:3])` the first variable (column 2) is plotted at x=1 and the second variable (column 3) is plotted at x=2. By capturing the return value of `boxplot` you can figure out the y values. Since you do not provide any data, I will illustrate with randomly generated data.

```
## Data
set.seed(42)
NumPts = 400
a = rnorm(NumPts)
b = rnorm(NumPts)
c = rnorm(NumPts)
CAT = sample(c("M", "N"), NumPts, replace=T)
mydata = data.frame(a,b,c, CAT)

## Find outliers
BP = boxplot(mydata[,2:3], col=c("chartreuse","gold"))
OUT2 = which(mydata[,2] %in% BP$out)
OUT3 = which(mydata[,3] %in% BP$out)

## Find outliers with category == M
M_OUT2 = OUT2[which(mydata$CAT[OUT2] == "M")]
M_OUT3 = OUT3[which(mydata$CAT[OUT3] == "M")]

## Plot desired points
points(rep(1, length(M_OUT2)),mydata[M_OUT2, 2], col="red")
points(rep(2, length(M_OUT3)),mydata[M_OUT3, 3], col="red")
```

[image: Boxplot with selected points colored]

Comment: There is a BP$group: a vector of the same length as out whose elements indicate to which group the outlier belongs. Shoudn't I use this? In case there are same values in both plots, then they are printed over both of them.

Comment: NVM. Just did it: 
OUT3 = which(mydata[,3] %in% BP$out[which(BP$group==2)])